# Is there a way to dynamically configure error pages for Exceptions in JSF/AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jsf, omnifaces, jsf-2.2

I would like to dynamically set an error page in JSF. Specifically what I would like to do is whenever I get a `ViewExpiredException` to refresh the page. I am currently using omnifaces `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` to manage my exception but it reads the error pages from `web.xml`.

Is there an easy way to do this? 
Should I consider client side navigation by using `onError` event or just overwrite `FullAjaxExceptionHandler.findErrorPageLocation` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads error pages from `web.xml` because that's the standard way how they are used if you didn't use JSF ajax in first place. In other words, the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` ensures that the exception handling and error page presentation behaves exactly the same as if when you wouldn't be using ajax by e.g. `<h:commandButton>` without `<f:ajax>`, or `<p:commandButton ajax="false">`, or because enduser has JS disabled.

You can indeed control it by extending the exception handler and overriding `findErrorPageLocation` method, but then it won't behave anymore the same way as the standard way.

Alternatively, and likely a better way in your specific case, is to just specify a specific error page for `ViewExpiredException` and grab the initial page by the usual request attribute and let JavaScript redirect to it on page load.

```
<h:outputScript>
    window.location = "#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}";
</h:outputScript>
```

As a bonus, it will work exactly the same way as when you wouldn't be using JSF ajax.

---

I only wonder how this all would improve the user experience. This is likely only more confusing to the enduser; a page which reloads itself without any additional feedback when the session has expired during a postback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right for the case where a user submits data, but in my case I want to handle ajax navigation (render another part of the page). In that case, I can't think of a reason why the user needs to know that the view expired. Am I missing something?

Comment: Uh, this way input forms aren't behaving as designed. All submitted data is lost, there's no feedback about successful/failed submit at all, the page is just reloaded. This all is very confusing. Like as you fill in a login form and the very same login form redisplays without feedback. You'd better show a "Sorry, your session has expired" error page along with a link to the original page with the form.

Comment: Point taken. How are websites like facebook and linkedin avoid this? Do they just keep the session alive forever? Do they refresh the page before it expires?

Comment: By stateless views, or by login with "remember me".